# bazel logging inside of a BUILD file

Tags: python, python-3.x, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-python

Hi I want to see what is being passed to a rule that is defined in a `rules.bzl` file. So I would like to add just a logging statement inside of either the `BUILD` file or the  `rules.bzl` file just to see what parameter was passed.  I realize there is a whole `--execution_log_binary_file` and there is a good deal of stuff to read up on, but I am definitely looking to do something just once and quick and dirty. Do I import `logging` module? Is it something else? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the builtin Starlark [`print()` function](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/globals/all#print) in `BUILD` or `.bzl` files to dump values Bazel's console.

Comment: but this prints it out right away and not during the execution

Comment: Execution of what? Almost all Starlark runs before Bazel starts running anything.

Comment: I see. But there are some env variable looking things in this print() output and I just assumed they would be further interpolated somewhere down the line.  But perhaps Im not really making sense, maybe these are not env variables

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing specifically what you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

[`bazel query --output=build //my/package:all`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/query.html#output-build) will print out the definitions of all the [targets](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-ref.html#targets) created by macros called from [`my/package/BUILD`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-ref.html#packages) by any `.bzl` file. This includes all the attributes passed to to various [rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-ref.html#rules) to create those targets.